# Saving preferences in localStorage

Tags: javascript, quiz, browser-storage

I am working on a small app to help my kids study their multiplication and addition.  And I have various preferences I want to be persisted between visits.  What do you think of the below to get the settings out of local storage?  I know I could do it even more simply by simply stringifying the whole object at once, but I want the preferences to contain the answers and I don't want to save all of the answers every time the preferences change...although as I write this that seems like less of an issue...this is for my kids so I don't care about supporting older browsers.

```
function getPrefs() {
        "use strict";

        getPrefs.prefs = getPrefs.prefs || new Object();
        var prefs = getPrefs.prefs;

        if (prefs.populated) return prefs;

        var localStorage = window['localStorage'];

        prefs.addAnswer = function (answer, correct) {
            this.answers.unshift(answer);
            if (correct) {
                this.correctAnswers++;
                localStorage.setItem("correctAnswers", this.correctAnswers.toString());
                if (this.correctAnswers % 12 === 0) {
                    this.level++;
                    localStorage.setItem("level", this.level.toString());
                }
            } else {
                this.wrongAnswers++;
                localStorage.setItem("wrongAnswers", this.wrongAnswers.toString());
            }
            localStorage.setItem("answers", JSON.stringify(this.answers.slice(0, 100)));
            this.answeredAdded();
        }

        prefs.answeredAdded = function () { };

        prefs.answers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("answers") || '[]');

        prefs.topValue = Number(localStorage.getItem("topValue"));
        prefs.bottomValue = Number(localStorage.getItem("bottomValue"));

        prefs.showHistory = localStorage.getItem("showHistory") === "false";
        prefs.operator = localStorage.getItem("operator") || "x";

        prefs.correctAnswers = Number(localStorage.getItem("correctAnswers") || 0);
        prefs.wrongAnswers = Number(localStorage.getItem("wrongAnswers") || 0);
        prefs.level = Number(localStorage.getItem("level") || "1");


        prefs.populated = true;

        return prefs;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Design

Since you want only one instance of preferences, you can make use of [the singleton pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript):

```
var prefs = (function () {
    var instance;

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) instance = new Prefs();
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();
```

Then you can call the method wherever needed: `prefs.getInstance()`.

You can also encapsulate initialisation logic into a constructor, it seems like you wanted to use OOP anyway:

```
function Prefs() {
    // init your properties here, use 'this', e.g:
    this.answers = [];
}

Prefs.prototype.addAnswer = function (answer, correct) {
    // use 'this' just as you did in your code
};
```

## `localStorage`

The way you deal  with `localStorage` seems ok to me. If you want, you can turn `correctAnswers` and `wrongAnwsers` into [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), tough syntax for them is a bit baroque:

```
Object.defineProperty(Prefs.prototype, 'correctAnswers', {
    set: function (val) {
        localStorage.setItem('correctAnswers', val);
        return val;
    }
});
```

Use it as you previously did: `this.correctAnswers++`.

## Minor issues

This line is useless:

```
var localStorage = window['localStorage'];
```

You can skip `toString` here:

```
localStorage.setItem("correctAnswers", this.correctAnswers.toString());
```

`topValue` and `bottomValue` don't have default values. They will be `NaN` if there is no such item in `localStorage`.

Comment: I had considered a singleton (one of the reasons I posted), but but couldn't really find a justification for that vs function.  The window['localStorage'] being useless, that was the example I've seen, but doesn't it expicitly define the scope so that if localStorage was define elsewhere it wouldn't conflict?  Not a problem at the moment, but it seemed a good practice. Asfor top and bottom, I was taking checking for that elsewhere to provide defaults, but this might be a better place to set it.

Comment: @jmoreno the `var localStorage` line is basically making a local variable the same name and instance of a global variable.  That line would be useful to exit gracefully in older browsers, in your case it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @pllee: yes, I was asking about the value of making a local variable with the same name and instance as a global, in case there was another local variable between my function and the global scope which has the same name but a different instance.  Not sure if that is being extra paranoid or not, but I'm looking to do things right.

Comment: Plavo, you modify the prototype outside of the constructor, what about doing it inside?  I like to keep code as self contained as possible.

Comment: @jmoreno it is still basically the same thing.  In this case `localStorage`, `window.localStorage` and `window['localStorage']` are all the exact same thing. Assigning a variable named localStorage to the localStorage object doesn't gain really any safety.

Comment: @jmoreno, so that modifications are applied each time the constructor is called? Syntax may be verbose (wait for ES6), but this is a standard way to do prototypical inheritance in JavaScript.

Comment: It's not that it's verbose, but that the method is added to the object after it is created.  I would prefer not to do monkey patching unless it is needed.  I see setting the value afterwords as similar to adding an event listener (I considered using an event,  but it seemed like over engineering for such a simple app).

Comment: "method is added to the object after it is created" what object are you referring to? Prototype? Instance? Anyway there is no "monkey patching" being done here, this is just how you do OOP in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Pavlo has a good answer I'll just comment on a few extra things.

You can use a closure to init your `prefs` object only once.  It is a little bit cleaner than putting a flag on it to show that it has been inited.  You can do something like:

```
var getPrefs = (function() {
    var prefs;

    return function() {
        if(prefs) {
            return prefs;
        }

        prefs = ...
    }
})();
```

The variable `prefs` will always be falsy the first time around.

Design wise I would just jsonify everything, there isn't much overhead and it makes things simpler without the need to cast everything.

JS coding tidbits:

Use `{}` over `new Object()` it is slightly cleaner and the preferred way.

You can use the `+` operator when casting `Numbers` `+'1'` will return the number `1` for example.

Comment: "You can use the + operator when casting Numbers" – please don't. Shorter isn't always better, software engineering learned that lessons the hard way from Perl.

Comment: I meant to make it a self invoking function, I'll update it.

Comment: Shorter isn't always better for thinks like variable/function names and for the most part readability but I would argue for this case it is.  The plus operator is widely known as a `Number` cast.  I would say this falls under something like `i++` vs `i += 1` I guess it is a preference but I will always choose `i++` (even ignoring the incrementing vs addition aspect).

Comment: `++` operator was intended to be used like so, while you are abusing typecasting with `+` operator.